# Html.Beginform not firing in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I've been using Html.Beginform for a while in MVC but now I encountered a strange problem. I have 3 submit buttons on my form that should trigger the action inside the Html.Beginform. The problem is, It is not firing. I don't know if it is the structure of my view or I just missed something.

Here is my view:

```
<div id="maincontent" class="row select_sales"><!--CONTENT START-->
    <div id="page-title" class="text-blue col-md-12"><h2>Create DocPack : @Model.DocumentPackageNumber</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="item1" style="color:#999999">Select Product</li>
        <li class="item2" style="color:#49afcd">Assign Manager and Planner</li>
        <li class="item3" style="color:#49afcd">Confirm DocPack</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="dv-body-content" class="col-md-12"><br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocumentPackage", "home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div id="select_product">
    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-7 col-md-offset-3" role="form">
      <div class="text-center">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Product</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="margin:0 auto; width:300px !important;">
              <option>Standard Life</option>
            </select>
          </div>
           <div>
            <a href="~/home/index" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Back&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirm1()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          </div>
      </div>
     </form>
     </div>

    <div id="select_sales" style="display:none">
          <form class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Sales Manager (PRC)</label>
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SalesManager, 
              new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = "John Doe" , text = "John Doe"  },
                   new { value = "Cambridge Wong"  , text = "Cambridge Wong"  },
                   new { value = "Will Smith"  , text = "Will Smith"  },
                   new { value = "Bryan Adams"  , text = "Bryan Adams"  },
                }, "value", "text", Model.SalesManager), new { @class="form-control"})
            </div><br />
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">AMG Financial Planner</label>
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmgFinancialPlanner,
              new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = "Sydney White" , text = "Sydney White"  },
                   new { value = "Bill Armstrong"  , text = "Bill Armstrong"  },
                   new { value = "Karen Michaels"  , text = "Karen Michaels"  }
                }, "value", "text", Model.AmgFinancialPlanner), new { @class="form-control"})
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="back1()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Back&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirm2()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
          </form>
     </div>

    <div id="existing_dockpack" style="display:none">
      <div class="text-center">
        <label>Do you have an existing Dockpack?</label>
        <p>Would you like to copy it?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="back2()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Back&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#existing-docpack-no" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#existing-docpack-yes" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="modal fade" id="existing-docpack-yes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><br />
            <h4 class="modal-title">Input existing Docpack Number</h4><br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrevDocumentPackageNumber, null, new { @class="form-control", @placeholder="DocPack number"})<br /><br />
            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm" />

          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="existing-docpack-no" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><br />
            <h4 class="modal-title">Single individual?</h4><br /><br />
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="No" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yes" />
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal --> 
    }

   </div><!--CONTENT END-->
```

Don't mind the divs. I placed the Html.Beginform right before the fields that I need are rendered. I have 3 submit buttons there, depending on the button, there will be some changes on the data. But that goes later, the main issue is that the action is not firing. I tried placing it at the top, the closing brace seems to be lost.

Here is my Home controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [InPrivate]
    public ActionResult CreateDocumentPackage(DocumentPackageDetailsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var documentPackage = new DocumentPackage() { 
            DocumentPackageNumber = viewModel.DocumentPackageNumber, 
            UserId = WebUser.CurrentUser.Id, Title = viewModel.DocumentPackageNumber, 
            DocumentPackageStatus = DocumentPackageStatus.Open, 
            Creator = WebUser.CurrentUser.Firstname + " " + WebUser.CurrentUser.Lastname, 
            IsSingleIndividual = viewModel.IsSingleIndividual,
            SalesManager = viewModel.SalesManager ?? "",
            AmgFinancialPlanner = viewModel.AmgFinancialPlanner ?? "",
            PrevDocumentPackageNumber = viewModel.PrevDocumentPackageNumber
        };
        _documentPackageRepository.Add(documentPackage);
        _documentPackageRepository.Save();

        _documentRepository.CreateDocument(1, documentPackage.Id, Convert.ToInt16(documentPackage.ClientId), WebUser.CurrentUser.Id);
        _documentRepository.CreateDocument(2, documentPackage.Id, Convert.ToInt16(documentPackage.ClientId), WebUser.CurrentUser.Id);
        _documentRepository.CreateDocument(3, documentPackage.Id, Convert.ToInt16(documentPackage.ClientId), WebUser.CurrentUser.Id);
        _documentRepository.CreateDocument(4, documentPackage.Id, Convert.ToInt16(documentPackage.ClientId), WebUser.CurrentUser.Id);

        return RedirectToAction("show", new { id = documentPackage.Id });
    }
```

I think the controller's fine. The problem I think is the View. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

i have check your html, it contains two form tags within Html.BeginForm()

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocumentPackage", "home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div id="select_product">
    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-7 col-md-offset-3" role="form">

<div id="select_sales" style="display:none">
    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" role="form">
```

remove your form tags and use only Html.BeginForm() then check its works for me.